# KnockoutJS Binding Issue - Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-2

I have what is likely a simple Knockout question but I'm a complete beginner with it.  I was tossed this page of code that someone else has worked on but never finished.

When this page first loads, the data is retrieved and the main grid loads properly.  The problem comes in when I attempt to auto-select the first record in the results so that a detail list gets filled out below the grid.

When that happens, I receive the following message.

**Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return selected.RequestLog.Timestamp }" , Message: Cannot read property 'Timestamp' of undefined**

Here is the code snippets with which I'm working.  The data coming back is from Entity Framework.

```
var siteLogModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.errorList = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.selected = ko.observable();

            self.updateErrorList = function (page) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Admin/ErrorPage",
                    data: { pageNum: page },
                    success: function (result) {
                        self.errorList(result);
                        self.selected(result[0]);

                        // Since we have success, add the click handler so we can get the details about a row by id.
                        //addRowHandlers();
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        jQuery("#status").text = result;
                    }
                });
            };
        };
```

This is the actual binding that tries to happen after the data is loaded.  RequestLog does not seem to exist at binding time, even though it **does** seem to be ok if I set a breakpoint in the above function on the line self.selected(result[0]).

I think this is a scope problem but I can't for the life of me think of how best to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <div class="param">
       <span>Time</span>
       <label data-bind="text: selected.RequestLog.Timestamp"></label>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:  Here is the document ready portion.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            var vm = new siteLogModel();
            vm.updateErrorList(0);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        });
```

Comment: What does your result object look like? Also, there may be an issue with how you are using observableArray. There is no need to pass the constructor an empty array (though it probably won't hurt) and you can use self.errorList.push(result) to add values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `selected` observable does not have a `.RequestLog` property at the time ko is evaluating the binding expression. That error is coming from javascript, not ko (though ko wraps the exception in the error message you see). When running, `selected.RequestLog === undefined` is true, and you can't invoke anything on undefined. It's like a null reference exception.

It makes sense if you are calling `applyBindings` before the ajax call finishes.

One way to fix this by doing a computed instead:

```
<div class="param">
   <span>Time</span>
   <label data-bind="text: selectedRequestLogTimestamp"></label>
</div>

self.selectedRequestLogTimestamp = ko.computed(function() {
    var selected = self.selected();
    return selected && selected.RequestLog
        ? selected.RequestLog.TimeStamp
        : 'Still waiting on data...';
});
```

With the above, nothing is ever being invoked on an undefined variable. Your label will display "Still waiting on data" until the ajax call finishes, then it will populate with the timestamp as soon as you invoke `self.selected(result[0])`.

Another way to solve it is by keeping your binding the same, but by giving the selected observable an initial value. You can leave all of your html as-is, and just to this:

```
self.selected = ko.observable({
    RequestLog: {
        TimeStamp: 'Still waiting on data'
    }
});
```

... and you will end up with the same result.

Why?

Any time you initialize an observable by doing something like `self.prop = ko.observable()`, the actual value of the observable is `undefined`. Try it out:

```
self.prop1 = ko.observable();
var prop1Value = self.prop1();
if (typeof prop1Value === 'undefined') alert('It is undefined');
else alert('this alert will not pop up unless you initialize the observable');
```

So to summarize what is happening:

1. You initialize your selected observable with a value equal to undefined in your viewmodel.
2. You call ko.applyBindings against the viewmodel.
3. ko parses the data-bind attributes, and tries to bind.
4. ko gets to the `text: selected.RequestLog.Timestamp` binding.
5. ko invokes selected(), which returns undefined.
6. ko tries to invoke .RequestLog on undefined.
7. ko throws an error, because undefined does not have a .RequestLog property.

All of this happens before your ajax call returns.

**Reply to comment #1**

Yes, you can call applyBindings after your ajax success event. However, that's typically not always what you *should* do. If you want to, here's one example of how it could be done:

```
self.updateErrorList = function (page) {
    self.updateErrorPromise = jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/ErrorPage",
        data: { pageNum: page },
        success: function (result) {
            self.errorList(result);
            self.selected(result[0]);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            jQuery("#status").text = result;
        }
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var vm = new siteLogModel();
    vm.updateErrorList(0);
    vm.updateErrorPromise.done(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
});
```

Yet another way would be to go ahead and eager-bind (applyBindings before the ajax call finishes), but wrap your markup in an if binding like so:

```
<div class="param" data-bind="if: selected">
   <span>Time</span>
   <label data-bind="text: selected.RequestLog.Timestamp"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Dan - that was an amazing answer!  Thank you!  I added my document.ready function to the original text to show how I'm calling the applybindings.  Is there a way to simply say 'wait and call applybindings after the call is completed', rather than do it property by property for each binding?  If I'm reading your answer correctly, then I'd have to do a snippet of code as you did for self.selectedRequestLogTimestamp for each binding that I have. Correct?

Comment: That is correct, and I have updated my answer with one way to do it. There are a dozen different ways you can use knockout. You might also want to look at the documentation for the `if` and `ifnot` bindings. You may just be able to wrap your other bindings within one of these to make ko delay the binding until after your selected observable has a value.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. To circle back around to your original suggestion, I have to ask (and show my knockout inexperience), where exactly does the function self.selectedRequestLogTimestamp get placed?  Inside of var siteLogModel = function (), I'm assuming.  I tried this and while I no longer received my original error, I never saw any data back and the default text never displayed.

Comment: Yes, that's where it is supposed to go. A computed works almost just like an observable -- when no args are passed, it should just return a value. I honestly can't say without setting breakpoints in the JS why it's not being called. Did you put it as the last member of the viewmodel ctor?

Comment: Nope I had not.  I did just try this though, on a whim.  I put my vm variable declaration outside of my document.ready function to the page level.  Then I referenced vm.selected in my bindings.  This seems to be working so far.  Does that makes sense to you or do you think I'm off-base in doing that?

Comment: I don't think you should have to sacrifice a ready closure to get it working. I also don't think you should have to invoke vm.selected in the binding, the way you are doing it, the whole vm should be an implicit this for the page. I do know what ko will execute all of your computed functions when the vm ctor first runs. That's how it discovers which observables the computed depends on.

Comment: .. update: "text: $data.myMissingProperty" fixes that